# Java EE. Получить клиентский IP в сервисе. Работа с EJBContext

Tags: java-ee, ejb

Есть проект, поделенный на два слоя (модуля): Rest и Service.
Нужно в сервисе получить клиентский IP адрес и хост. Взять их можно из request в Rest модуле. Передавать каждый раз в качестве параметров метода из rest в service - не хочется. Хочется сделать это неявно, скрытно.
Смотрю в сторону EJBContext.getContextData()

В rest-модуле создаю фильтр:

```
@Provider
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyContainerRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

@Context
private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

@Inject
private ApplicationService applicationService;

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    try {
        applicationService.getEJBContext().getContextData().put("ipAddress", servletRequest.getRemoteAddr());
        applicationService.getEJBContext().getContextData().put("ipHost", servletRequest.getRemoteHost());
    } catch(Exception ingnore) {

    }
}
}

@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class ApplicationService {

@Resource
private EJBContext ejbContext;

public EJBContext getEJBContext() {
    return ejbContext;
}
}
```

Если в фильтре сделать

> @Resource
>   private EJBContext ejbContext;

то контекст не находится

Задумываю в сервис модуле заинжектить EJBContext и достать оттуда все что нужно.
Но в моем примере

```
applicationService.getEJBContext().getContextData() - NullPointerException
```

Подскажите в чем ошибка и правильной ли дорогой иду? Может есть другие решения?